# Qualtrics Randomized Survey Download not working

Tags: download, survey, qualtrics

I have created and run a survey in which there are 4 randomized conditions. The conditions are randomized in Survey Flow by creating 4 Group elements, each with 2 questions in it, and having those 4 Group elements under a Randomizer element so only one of those four groups is presented. When downloading the data, the randomized conditions are not shown. We are selecting "Export viewing order data for randomized surveys" but all we are getting is a column called "FL_22 - Block Randomizer - Display Order" with the variables being called "FL_13", "FL_12", "FL_16", "FL_19" so there is no way for us to know what conditions in the Randomizer element these numbers correspond to. Any idea how we can obtain the names of the randomized variables?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Survey Flow, check the "Show Flow IDs" box in the upper right.